# Calculation Returns Zero Value Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a sub in Access 2010 that takes the total cost of a column in millions of dollars (`txtSumEstimatedValue`) and multiplies it by 1,000,000 to give the cost in whole dollars (`DesignEstProgramValue`). The problem is that whenever one of the costs is changed, the final cost becomes 0 and I don't know why. I've tried adding `Parent.Dirty=False` but that didn't work.

This is the code that I'm using.

```
Private Sub Est_Value_AfterUpdate()

    'Recalculate estimated value
    Me.Recalc
    Parent.[DesignEstProgramValue] = (Me.txtSumEstimatedValue) * 1000000
    'Update date
    Parent.[UpdatedCosts] = Date
    Parent![Updated Costs].Requery
    Parent!Text263.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you run us through an example? Of what all is going on for this to occur?

Comment: So there's a table with a list of costs. At the end, there's a sum. On another page, there's the same sum but in dollars instead of millions of dollars, When I change one of the costs, the sum adds correctly but the cost in dollars on the other page becomes 0.

Comment: What are the data types? Are you 100% sure you're working with Numbers? Did you try to refresh the "other" page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine this simpler version of your code ...

```vb
Private Sub Est_Value_AfterUpdate()
    Parent.[DesignEstProgramValue] = (Me.txtSumEstimatedValue) * 1000000
End Sub
```

*Est_Value_AfterUpdate* runs when the user has changed the value in a control named *Est_Value*.  But within that procedure, you're not using the value of *Est_Value*.  Instead you're using the value of a control named *txtSumEstimatedValue*.  What is the value in that control?

Find out by including this line in your procedure.

```vb
MsgBox "The value of txtSumEstimatedValue is '" & Nz(Me.txtSumEstimatedValue.Value, "Null") & "'"
```

Since you know *Est_Value* contains the correct source value when *Est_Value_AfterUpdate* runs, use that in your procedure:

```vb
Private Sub Est_Value_AfterUpdate()
    'Parent.[DesignEstProgramValue] = (Me.txtSumEstimatedValue) * 1000000
    Parent.[DesignEstProgramValue] = Me.Est_Value.Value * 1000000
End Sub
```

Comment: txtSumEstimatedValue and Est_Value are the same thing. txtSumEstimatedValue is in the table, and gets copied to a box outside the table.

Comment: Please add the `MsgBox` line I suggested and then tell us what Access reports for the value of txtSumEstimatedValue.

Comment: It says, The value is of txtSumEstimatedValue is "

Comment: Excellent!  When you ask Access to multiply that by 1000000, what result do you expect?

Comment: Whatever is in txtSumEstimatedValue times 1,000,000. Ex. if txtSumEstimatedValue is $2.5, DesignEstProgramValue should be $2,500,000.

Comment: But *txtSumEstimatedValue* is an empty string ... `''`.  What does `Me.Est_Value.Value * 1000000` give you?